# Reduce using a lot of useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project there are a lot of inputs so I've created each one of its own `useState`, is there any way to reduce the use of `useState`

part of the code

```
const [OldGpa, setOldGpa] = useState(0);
const [oldHours, setOldHours] = useState(0);

const [firstHour, setFirstHour] = useState(0);
const [secondHour, setSecondHour] = useState(0);
const [threadHour, setThreadHour] = useState(0);
const [fourthHour, setFourthHour] = useState(0);
const [fifthHour, setFifthHour] = useState(0);
const [sixthHour, setSixthHour] = useState(0);
const [seventhHour, setSeventhHour] = useState(0);

const [firstPoint, setFirstPoint] = useState(0)
const [secondPoint, setSecondPoint] = useState(0)
const [threadPoint, setThreadPoint] = useState(0)
const [fourthPoint, setFourthPoint] = useState(0)
const [fifthPoint, setFifthPoint] = useState(0)
const [sixthPoint, setSixthPoint] = useState(0)
const [seventhPoint, setSeventhPoint] = useState(0)

const [GPA, setGPA] = useState(0)
```

code path: src/componentes/Form.js
you can find the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-smoke-yz1mk5?file=/src/components/Form/Form.js

Comment: You could make hours and points arrays: `const [hours, setHours] = useState([0, 0, 0,....])` and then apply the same idea to create a `points` state. You can map these arrays in your render method also to help reduce repetition there and use the index of the number in the array to work out what you need to update.

Comment: *"you can find the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-smoke-yz1mk5?file=/src/components/Form/Form.js"* If you think we need that code to answer the question, put it in the question itself, not just off-site. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [also this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: good idea but in input how can get the value dependant index in the array

Comment: @AhmedRadi - `<input value={hours[1]} />` (instead of `secondHour`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok thank you bro about this information I will keep it in mind

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I put the link to the code if anyone wants to see more but the question does not need to the code

Comment: You shouldn't split every single piece of data in its own state. Instead, group values that belong together in a single `useState` and make partial updates on that structure (probably through a model/entity, don't make the view hold all the logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use any library, you can make all of your inputs an object like so :

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    OldGpa: 0,
    oldHours: 0,
    firstHour: 0,
    secondHour: 0,
    thirdHour: 0,
    fourthHour: 0,
    fifthHour: 0,
    sixthHour: 0,
    seventhHour: 0,
    firstPoint: 0,
    secondPoint: 0,
    thirdPoint: 0,
    fourthPoint: 0,
    fifthPoint: 0,
    sixthPoint: 0,
    seventhPoint: 0
});
```

Now your state in an object so you have to "bind" value with `value={inputs.property}`

Your inputs will need a name attribute in order to update the right property on this object (understand, name attribute will have to be the same as the object property).
You'll need to "copy" the prevState like so:

```
setInputs(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [name] : value
}))
```

Where name and value come from `event`

E.G

```
const handleInputs = (event) => {
    // destructuring the object
    let {target } = event;
    let { name, value } = target;


    setInputs(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [name] : value
    }))
}
```

Or you can destructure the event right into the function parameter like so:

```
const handleInputs = ({target: { value, name}}) => {
    setInputs(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [name] : value
    }))
}
```

Comment: How do I get the data I'm trying to use "input [nameOfInupt]" but it's not working

Comment: OK, no problem I will use dot notation

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this as a reference :

```
function init(initialCount) {
  return {count: initialCount};
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    case 'reset':
      return init(action.payload);
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialCount, init);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'reset', payload: initialCount})}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Similarly , you can modify according to your use case:

So, the answer to your question is ... to use useReducer instead of useState .

Answer (score 0):

```
// Outside the component:
const initialHours = Array(7).fill(0);
const initialPoints = Array(7).fill(0);

// Inside the component:
const [OldGpa, setOldGpa] = useState(0);
const [oldHours, setOldHours] = useState(0);

const [hours, setHours] = useState(initialHours);
const [points, setPoints] = useState(initialPoints);

const [GPA, setGPA] = useState(0)
```

Then whenever you used `secondHour`, for instance, you'd use `hours[1]` instead.

Instead of `setSecondHour(newValue)`, it would be:

```
setHours(hours => {
    hours = hours.slice(); // Copy the array
    hours[1] = newValue;
    return hours;
});
```

Sometimes you see people do that with spread and multiple `slice` calls, or with `Object.assign`, but to me those are clunky and unnecessarily complex. If you want to avoid rewriting that logic every time (which is a reasonable thing to want), write a utility function:

```
function setArrayElement(array, index, value) {
    array = array.slice();
    array[index] = value;
    return array;
}
```

and use that when setting the second value:

```
setHours(hours => setArrayElement(hours, 1, newValue));
```

If you want, you can combine things further into an object that you store in state, as [shown in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState` does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({});
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```
>
> Another option is [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.

*(I'm not sure I agree with the "more suited" part, but `useReducer` is another option.)*

Answer (score 0):

This way also can be used to reduce the usage of multiple useStates. But, when comparing Runtime performance this way cannot be recomended.

```
const [{ OldGpa, oldHours,firstHour,secondHour }, setSuggest] = useState({
    OldGpa:0, oldHours:0,firstHour:0,secondHour:0,threadHour:0, fourthHour:0
    });
```

[Are many useStates better than useState(object)?](https://thoughtspile.github.io/2021/10/11/usestate-object-vs-multiple/)

I suggest you to use useReducer
[useReducer vs useState](https://dev.to/spukas/3-reasons-to-usereducer-over-usestate-43ad)  [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#additional-hooks)

Comment: If author is used to store i can't disagree !

Comment: If you mean storing the state,The useReducer Hook is used to store and update states, just like the useState Hook. It accepts a reducer function as its first parameter and the initial state as the second. [reference](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-usereducer-hook-ultimate-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object and put all the inputs inside it.

```
const [inputs, setInputs]=useState({
        OldGpa: 0, 
        oldHours: 0, 
        firstHour: 0, 
        secondHour: 0,
        threadHour: 0,
        fourthHour: 0, 
        fifthHour: 0, 
        sixthHour: 0, 
        seventhHour: 0,
        firstPoint: 0,
        secondPoint: 0,
        threadPoint: 0,
        fourthPoint: 0,
        fifthPoint: 0, 
        sixthPoint: 0, 
        seventhPoint: 0, 
        
        GPA: 0,
        })
```

and then have a function handleChange to pass the input to the states:

```
const handleChange=(e)=>{
    setInputs({...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

and then call it from every input something like:

```
<input type="number" name='OldGpa' onChange={handleChange}
          value={inputs.OldGpa} />
```

...

```
<input type="number" name='OldHours' onChange={handleChange}
              value={inputs.OldHours} />
```

Comment: How do I get the data I'm trying to use "inputs[nameOfInupt]" but it's not working

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. it's an object if you want the data OldGpa you do inputs.OldGpa

Comment: Well, this is the dot notation I talk about bracket notation

Comment: OK, no problem I will use dot notation

Comment: I'm not used to it maybe try inputs["nameOfInput"] with the quotes

Comment: also, not work.

Comment: If you want to get, say, "oldHours" value in the object you'll have to write `inputs['oldHours']`